# Auto increment temporary column in select statement MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

Hello i use this type of sentence to return an auto increment column in my prepared statement selects

```
cnt := cnt + 1

        SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM (SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS id, a.idProducto idProducto, a.idExProducto idExterno, trim(a.descripcion) nombreProducto, trim(a.descripcionAlt) nombreLargoProducto, trim(a.serial) serial,',    
                        ' a.peso, a.volumen, a.IdTpoGrupo, trim(b.descripcion) nombreGrupo,',
                        ' a.idTpoLinea, trim(c.descripcion) nombreLinea,',                          
                        ' a.idTpoMarca, trim(d.descripcion) nombreMarca,', 
                        ' a.idTpoUnidad, trim(e.descripcion) nombreTipoUnidad,', 
                        ' CASE WHEN a._estado = 1 THEN ''true'' ELSE ''false'' END estado, ',  
                        ' g.nombreArchivo imagen ',  
                        ' FROM tblProducto a',          
                        ' INNER JOIN tblProducto_TpoGrupo b ON a.IdTpoGrupo = b.IdTpoGrupo',
                        ' INNER JOIN tblProducto_TpoLinea c ON a.idTpoLinea = c.idTpoLinea',
                        ' INNER JOIN tblProducto_TpoMarca d ON a.idTpoMarca = d.idTpoMarca',
                        ' INNER JOIN tblTpoUnidadMedida e ON a.idTpoUnidad = e.idTpoUnidadMed ',
                        ' LEFT JOIN tblProductoXImagen f ON a.idProducto = f.idProducto  AND f._estado=1',
                        ' LEFT JOIN tblImagen g on f.idImagen = g.idImagen AND g._estado=1',
                        ' WHERE a._estado<2 ',whereLike,whereConcat, ' order by idProducto ) allrecords');             
                        
                        
                        
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

that works perfect on MySQL 5, but now in MySQL 8 is deprecated and my transaction return a warning, but the warning stop the execution of my stored procedure, i want to know if there is a solution to can achieve this behavior in MySQL 8.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show us your entire query - or a minimum reproducible example that demonstrates what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions. The logic you sem to want is:

```
row_number() over(order by idProducto) as id
```

This gives you an incrementing integer value, that starts at `1` and increments according to `idProducto`. If two rows in the resultset have the same `idProducto`, it is undefined which one will be ordered "first" (it is, however, guaranteed that they will not get the same row number) - in that case, you might want to add one or more columns to the `order by` clause, so you do get a predictable, stable result.